# Which board to select for ESP32-S3-WROOM in PlatformIO?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, esp32, platformio

I have an `ESP32-S3-WROOM-1U` and would like to use `PlatformIO` with vscode to program it, what board do I need to set in the `platformio.ini` file?
I've tried:

```
[env:esp32s3box]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32s3box
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

but am getting the following output on the serial monitor:

```
ELF file SHA256: ad858c055791c095

E (153) esp_core_dump_flash: Core dump flash config is corrupted! CRC=0x7bd5c66f instead of 0x0
Rebooting...
ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0xc (RTC_SW_CPU_RST),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40376d60
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3808,len:0x44c
load:0x403c9700,len:0xbe4
load:0x403cc700,len:0x2a68
entry 0x403c98d4
E (84) spi_flash: Detected size(8192k) smaller than the size in the binary image header(16384k). Probe failed.

assert failed: do_core_init startup.c:328 (flash_ret == ESP_OK)


Backtrace: 0x40377152:0x3fceb180 0x4037a779:0x3fceb1a0 0x40380081:0x3fceb1c0 0x42006a00:0x3fceb2f0 0x40376ac3:0x3fceb320 0x403cd823:0x3fceb350 0x403cdae2:0x3fceb380 0x403c9929:0x3fceb4b0 0x40045c01:0x3fceb570 |<-CORRUPTED
```

So I tried:

```
[env:esp32s3]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32s3
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

But am getting:
``Resolving esp32s3 dependencies...
UnknownBoard: Unknown board ID 'esp32s3'

```
What `board` do I need to select to make this work?
```

Comment: This builds for me - but it fails to upload

```
[env:esp32-s3-devkitm-1]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32-s3-devkitm-1
framework = arduino
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never had that exact message in PlatformIO but it sounds that your board has 8mb or flash and the esp32s3box has 16mb so PlatformIO can't write the binary correctly.

The board type you specify in platformio.ini is just a pointer to a .h file in the platformio configuration that contains mapping of the pins and some preset bits of info like the cpu speed, flash size etc

Most of the time if your board is pretty generic (no fancy stuff like built in screen, battery charger, camera etc) you can simply use some other generic board type, something like

This one is 8mb flash

```
[env:esp32-s3-devkitc-1]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32-s3-devkitc-1
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200

; try enabling or disabling this line
board_build.mcu = esp32s3
```

I use this one a lot but I think it's for 4mb flash

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

Comment: Are you sure `esp32dev` will work for ESP32-S3? They do not have the exact same hardware.

Comment: look on  https://docs.platformio.org > Boards > Espresiff 32 and see if you can find a close match, you can tweak the .ini with various flags. These settings in the .ini are just shortcuts to .json files that you can technically make your own custom one if you want, they are in the platformio install folder (on a Mac it's a hidden .platformio) and then under platforms/espressif32. Also in the "packages" folder there will be a folder like "framework-arduinoespressif32/variants" where the pins_arduino.h describes the pin mapping for each board type, again all that can be modified manually.

Answer (score 0):

try adding these into you Platformio.ini if you have 16M flash and also PSRAM:

```
  ;partitions table 
  board_build.arduino.partitions = app3M_fat9M_16MB.csv
  ;flash and psram IO mode
  board_build.arduino.memory_type = qio_opi
  ;if you have PSRAM
  build_flags = -D BOARD_HAS_PSRAM
  ;assert flash size
  board_upload.flash_size = 16MB
```

so change these settings to match you 8M flash, especially partitions/memory_type/flash_size.

It works in my platformio ,so good luck!